# Echoing extra whitespaces in string

Tags: php, whitespace

How do you include whitespace in a php echo statement, so that the echo will output the same results as a call from the database?

```
$query = "SELECT response FROM allData WHERE response REGEXP 'i am        here'";
echo $query;
```

**Result:**

SELECT response FROM allData WHERE response REGEXP 'i am        here'

**Need Result:**

```
SELECT response FROM allData WHERE response REGEXP 'i am        here'
```

Answer (score 1):

The spaces are there, just look at your source in browser. If you want them rendered in html, then you'll need to replace the extra spaces with `&nbsp;`

```
echo str_replace(' ','&nbsp;',$query);
```

In this case because you're echoing out an SQL statement, then it might be better to use a `pre` tag around it.

```
echo "<pre>$query</pre>";
```

Comment: Or perhaps `<pre>`

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a `text/plain` content type, or replace spaces with `&nbsp;` (something like `str_replace(' ', '&nbsp;', $string)`).

The reason for this is that whitespace is not syntactically relevant in HTML.

Comment: You forgot the semi colon `&nbsp;`

Comment: Thank you @JeffPuckettII

Answer (score 0):

If you want to echo such strings and always display all space characters, then consider `white-space: pre` or use `<pre>` tag.